# Jquery change content on click with multiple levels

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

**The problem:**

I am trying to make a little jQuery content box whereby a user click on which section they are interested out of the 3 top level choices. Once they select one, they see a list of links within here. Clicking on one of these links then loads a youtube video embedded in the div.

So at the moment I have it work so that a user can click what will be a tab, this then shows the list within the tab. The next part, where a user clicks on the video name, which then loads the `li` item or `div` with the embedded media, doesn't work.

**I have a demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/CVyAD/

Please note some of the class names are similar, i just quickly threw this together to try demo my problem as it is.

I'm not sure I am approaching this in the right manner, and if there may be a better way to achieve what I am doing. Any pointers, tips would be appreciated. The example feels close, but messy. And i can't see why the 3rd level does not show, i used the same principle for it as the level above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because your id's were coming in as vidsvid-1 instead of vids1... check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CVyAD/2/

```
-$(document).ready(function() {
    var activeId = $(".active").attr("id").replace("tab",""); 
    $("#content" + activeId).show();


    $(".tab li").click(function() {
      $(".controls").hide();
      $(".tab li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active")
      var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id").replace("tab","");
      $("#content" + id).show();
   });

    $(".tabAlt li").click(function() {
      $(".videos").hide();
      $(".tabAlt li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active")
      var id = $(this).closest("li").attr("id").replace("tabAlt","");
      id = id.replace("vid-",""); //this is the line i added
      $("#vids" + id).show();
   });
});
```

Comment: it looks like you were trying to do this with the `.replace("tabAlt","")`, so you could also substitute that out for `"vid-",""` and have the same affect

Comment: That works, but only on the first level, if you click 'control 2' then try and get a third level it doesnt work?

Comment: because you only have vids1 - vids3... you don't have a ul with an id for vids4 - vids9

Comment: Ah sorry, i was looking at that wrong, i see how it's working. Thank you!